# Responsive page after updating database

Tags: php, ajax

How can I make the following code to be called by AJAX, i.e., after clicking on the link to update the database, and updating the page in my browser without reloading it?

```
<?php

$server = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$pass = "";
$database = "test";

mysql_connect($server, $user, $pass) or die ("check mysql settings");
mysql_select_db($database) or die ("database not found");

$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM settings ");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($data)) {
    $images = $row["images"];
    if($images == "yes") {
        echo "<a href='index.php?img=no'>Do not show images on this site</a>";
    } else {
        echo "<a href='index.php?img=yes'>Show images on this site</a>";
    }
}

$img = $_GET["img"];
if ($img == "yes") {
    mysql_query("update settings set images='yes'");
} else {
    mysql_query("update settings set images='no'");
}
```

Comment: Worth a read before you do anything else -https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php

Comment: its just an example to be understand, i will use mysqli.

Comment: You will need to write some javascript that uses jquery to implement your ajax.  So I would do some reading on those topics.

Comment: i know that, but i don't know how to code that jquery function for this code.